# Perform Query in Siebel using SWE api and CURL

Tags: curl, siebel

I'm try to perform a query in Oracle Siebel using [SWE API](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/PortalFrame/PortalFrameDelConExtWebApps.html).
I used [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31104_02/books/MoblConn/MoblConnWorkwSMC7.html#wp115444) approach with these steps:

1. Logging into the app
2. Navigate to Screen I want to query
3. Invoke the NewQuery Method
4. Perform the query

All goes well until step 4. As [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31104_02/books/MoblConn/MoblConnWorkwSMC7.html#wp115444) says

> Invoke the ExecuteQuery method and specify a value to indicate the search criteria.
>
> In the following example, query for a record name called **IP_Webserver**:
>   http://localhost/smc_enu/start.swe?SWECmd=InvokeMethod&SWEApplet=SMC+Opportunity+List+Applet&SWEView=SMC+Opportunity+View&SWENeedContext=false&SWEReqRowId=0&SWEBID=-1&SWEMethod=ExecuteQuery&SWESetMarkup=XML&**Name=IP_Webserver**

So I tried this approach, building the url and adding at the end the field I want to query and the value I need.
This is an abstract of the list I want to query

```
<LIST>
  <RS_HEADER>
     <COLUMN REQUIRED="FALSE" ID="501" NAME="ContactNumber" TEXT_BASED="TRUE" HTML_TYPE="Text" READ_ONLY="FALSE" LIST_EDITABLE="Y" NUMBER_BASED="FALSE" CALCULATED="FALSE" DATATYPE="text" SCALE="0" TYPE="Text" TEXT_LENGTH="64" FIELD="ContactNumber" HIDDEN="FALSE" TOTAL_REQUIRED="FALSE" DISPLAY_NAME="Codice Contatto"/>
     <COLUMN REQUIRED="TRUE" ID="502" NAME="CallType" TEXT_BASED="TRUE" HTML_TYPE="Text" READ_ONLY="FALSE" LIST_EDITABLE="Y" NUMBER_BASED="FALSE" CALCULATED="FALSE" DATATYPE="text" SCALE="0" TYPE="Text" TEXT_LENGTH="30" FIELD="CallType" HIDDEN="FALSE" TOTAL_REQUIRED="FALSE" DISPLAY_NAME="Tipologia"/>
     <COLUMN REQUIRED="FALSE" ID="505" NAME="Login" TEXT_BASED="TRUE" HTML_TYPE="Text" READ_ONLY="FALSE" LIST_EDITABLE="Y" NUMBER_BASED="FALSE" CALCULATED="FALSE" DATATYPE="text" SCALE="0" TYPE="Text" TEXT_LENGTH="50" FIELD="Login" HIDDEN="FALSE" TOTAL_REQUIRED="FALSE" DISPLAY_NAME="Operatore"/>
     <!-- more columns -->
  </RS_HEADER>
  <RS_DATA>
    <!-- ALL DATA --> 
  </RS_DATA>
</LIST>
```

The field i want to query is the 3th (NAME="Login") so I produced this url

> http://localhost/smc_enu/start.swe?SWECmd=InvokeMethod&SWEMethod=ExecuteQuery&SWEView=MY_VIEW&SWEApplet=MY_APPLET&SWESetMarkup=XML&SWEReqRowId=0&SWEBID=-1&SWEDataOnly=TRUE&SWESetNoTemp=TRUE&Login=MYLOGIN&_sn=BfiiwHEVNHao60VbIikS7g9VxJPyMAnzmjbv3XXXBrdqRcopKmc6d-0cwRXSX2C3

But **I got all results instead of the ones I requested for**, like I did not provide a search criteria at all.

Am I missing something into request I built? Is this the right way to perform a query to Siebel via SWE api?

**NOTE**: I tried using POST method too, but in this case the output wont be XML (like I did an empty GET request)
**NOTE 2**: I do not have Admin access to the Siebel application.